# Is the construction »sollen ... sein soll« correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb

My question refers to the last sentence of the below paragraph from the article  “[Dumpingvorwürfe. Was Trump gegen deutsche Stahlhersteller hat](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/unternehmen/stahl-warum-donald-trump-deutschland-dumping-vorwirft-a-1141696.html)” in *Der Spiegel*:

> Darf die Trump-Regierung das?
>
> Grundsätzlich schon. Zwar haben sich die USA als Mitglied der
>   Welthandelsorganisation (WTO) dazu verpflichtet, Handelspartner nicht
>   zu diskriminieren. Allerdings erlaubt Artikel sechs des allgemeinen
>   Zoll- und Handelsabkommens GATT ausdrücklich Antidumpingzölle, wenn
>   ein Produkt im Ausland "unter seinem normalen Wert" verkauft wird. *Die
>   Zölle **sollen** dabei nicht höher **sein soll**, "als die Dumpingspanne bei
>   diesem Erzeugnis".*

Is *soll* before the comma redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not really redundant; rather, it is incorrect. I suspect this is a result of editing the sencence.

But as your feeling seems to tell you, removing the *soll* makes it correct:

> Die Zölle sollen dabei nicht höher sein, "als die Dumpingspanne
>   bei diesem Erzeugnis".

The second *soll* is a finite verb in last position. To keep it, you would have to change the sentence to a subordinate sencence (and *Zölle* to singular); for example, using *wobei* instead of *dabei*:

> [Artikel sechs erlaubt Zölle], wobei der Zoll nicht höher sein soll, "als die Dumpingspanne
>   bei diesem Erzeugnis".

Although the changing of the numerus of the repeated subject seems a bit awkward.

Comment: But the comma in front of "als" is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

*»soll«* is incorrect and the following comma is incorrect (since *»als«* starts no subordinate clause here). There's also a number problem concerning *»Die Zölle sollen«* (plural) and *»bei diesem Erzeugnis«* (singular).

All in all I would rephrase the last two sentences to:

> Allerdings erlaubt Artikel sechs des allgemeinen Zoll- und
>   Handelsabkommens GATT ausdrücklich Antidumping**zoll**, wenn ein Produkt
>   im Ausland "unter seinem normalen Wert" verkauft wird. **Der Zoll** soll dabei nicht höher sein "als die Dumpingspanne bei diesem
>   Erzeugnis".